# Package 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' has no installation candidate

Tags: 14.04, apt, java, fonts, .ttf

I am having a Java based web application running in Amazon EC2 Ubuntu server. I use Jasper reports to generate some reports in PDF format. I built these reports using 'Jaspersoft Studio'

Now, when I try to generate reports, I get this error

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.jrfontnotfoundexception font 'Times New Roman' is not available to the jvm
```

So, I decided to install the Microsoft fonts. I typed,

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

It didn't work at all. Instead, it gave me the below notice

```
$ sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ttf-mscorefonts-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' has no installation candidate
```

How can I solve this issue?

**Update**

My `source.list` contains below. am I safe to edit?

```
       ## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl
#

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main
deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
# deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
# deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
# deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
```

Comment: after installing font using @mchid method is jasper font issue solved ? or do we need to do anything else ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are two methods you can use to install the software.

**Command line install**

```
echo "deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/multiverse.list 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

---

**Easy install**

Open ubuntu software center, click on **Edit** and select **Software Sources** from the dropdown menu.

Place a tick in the box for **Software restricted by copyright or legal issues (multiverse)**.

You may be asked for a password.

When you are done, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: You might have to check your commands again. I can see a non closed quotation mark. And, I have no GUI.

Comment: @MIT_Love Thanks, it's closed on line 3 but you have to scroll right to see it. I actually copy and pasted the commands to test if this would work correctly.

Comment: OH, OK. The command line version seems to be specialized for EC2, that is better.. Let me try.

Comment: @MIT_Love alternatively, following A.B.'s advice above, you could just edit the /etc/apt/sources.list file by removing the comment mark (# ) from the beginning of lines 33, 35, and 45.

Answer (score 3):

**You have a tag 12.04 but your sources.list is for 14.04?**

The package is in the <kbd>multiverse</kbd> repositories.

Edit your `sources.list`

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After your update in your question, simply remove the `#` in the front of each line starting with `deb` and with the entry `multiverse`

Here is the complete list based on your `list` file for a copy and paste

```
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl
#

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main
deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
```

Do the same in `/etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl`

After that

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

---

Special notes for  *Amazon EC2 Ubuntu server*

1. Edit your `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`

   ```
   nano /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
   ```

   and add

   ```
   apt_preserve_sources_list: true
   ```
2. Add additionally PPAs or non-Ubuntu sources in separate `list` files in the folder

   ```
   /etc/apt/sources.list.d
   ```
3. Make your changes in `/etc/apt/sources.list` in

   ```
   /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl
   ```

   too, to survive a re-bundle.

Comment: I can't do these gui things. As mentioned I am in ubuntu Amazon instance. Whatever I do need to be done via command line.

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry

Comment: what did you mean by edit the list? Do I have to copy and paste the list you have mentioned?

Comment: And another update...

Comment: In my source file, it has a comment line which tells the below - `
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl
#

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.`. is it safe to edit?

Comment: Yes, it's safe, if you make your changes in `/etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl` too. Updated my answer =)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is it actually mean by "Safe" and "Un safe" here? "Unsafe" means I will have to add the lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list` everytime I reboot? If yes, then that is not an issue for me. And, to where should I add `apt_preserve_sources_list: true` in `cloud.cfg` file?

Comment: Search for an existing entry `apt_preserve_sources_list` and change or add the line at the end of the file. In my understand, the entry will survive a reboot, but not a re-bundle. Therefore make the changes in `/etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl`. This file is the template file, if the re-bundle creates a new `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: You have been contiously helping me. It is highly appreciated. Thank you. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: and another one!